# Snowflake SQL Json string- get value between two words

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working in snowflake sql and have a json string that I need to pull the value between two words.

For example:

This is a test ~Message: This is a test~

I need a function that would pull the value from ~Message:..... to the next Tilde. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi - so what have you tried and what issue are you facing?

Comment: I'd use SPLIT_PART() to do this, but I'm not clear whether you want everything between the tildas or everything inside the tildas after the Message:.

Comment: Yes, everything between the tildas but the string has multiple tildas. thanks